# Python CSV to extract and time values from element

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I write a python script to store output of pgRouting(in PostgreSQL) in a CSV file, and the code and part of CSV file looks like,

```
import sys, os
os.chdir('C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop')
print os.getcwd()

#set up psycopg2 environment
import psycopg2

#driving_distance module
query = """
    select *
    from shortest_path ($$
        select
            gid as id,
            source::int4 as source,
            target::int4 as target,
            pi::double precision as cost,
            pi_rcost::double precision as reverse_cost
        from network
        $$, %s, %s, %s, %s
    )
"""

#make connection between python and postgresql
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'TC_area' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = 'xxxx'")
cur = conn.cursor()

#count rows in the table
cur.execute("select count(*) from network")
result = cur.fetchone()
k = result[0] + 1                #number of points = number of segments + 1

#run loops
#import csv module
import csv
import tempfile
import shutil
rs = []
i = 1
l = 1
filename = 'test.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    while i <= k:
        while l <= k:
            cur.execute(query, (i, l, False, True))
            rs.append(cur.fetchall())
            element = list(rs)
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
            writer.writerow(element)
            rs = []
            l = l + 1
        l = 1
        i = i + 1

conn.close()
```

[image]

Now I want to do 3 things,

1. extract every second object in the bracket from the element in every row, like **0.0** in the first row and **0.844, 0.0** in the second row, ...etc.
2. times every object extracted from every row, take the second row as an example, **0.844 * 0.0 = 0**, so **there will be one result in each row.**
3. write these products in the CSV file

How to do this？ Can I do this task in just one step？

I am using python 2.7.4 and PostgreSQL 8.4 under Windows 8.1 x64.

---

**UPDATE#1**
I added the following 2 lines in my script (thanks, shaktimaan),

```
[a[-1] for a in element]
product = reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, [a[-1] for a in element])
```

and here's the part of the output,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence all you need to know is how to multiple all elements in a list. That can be done using the [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) method like this:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, a_list)
```

Now, looking at your code, each entry in your csv is generated by the statement:

```
element = list(rs)
```

As an example, `element` can have this:

```
[(1, -1, 0.0), (1, 1, 0.844), (2, -1, 0)]
```

You need to multiply the third number of each of those inner tuples. So, create a list on the fly that extracts the third element of every sub tuple

```
[a[-1] for a in element]
```

Now plug this in the `reduce()` from earlier:

```
product = reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, [a[-1] for a in element])
```

This prints `0.0` for the above example. Now that you have the product, use that as and how you want to print it in the output CSV.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, but how to create a list to store the third element of every sub tuple?

Comment: @heinz `[a[-1] for a in element]` is doing it. It uses list comprehension. `a[1]` refers to last element of every sub-tuple in this case

Comment: you're right, and I will edit my post to point out the problem I neglect in the very beginning, thanks for your reply.